# Intel AC 3160 adapter: Can't connect to router after restarting

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, internet, intel-wireless

Everytime, I restart the computer my wireless won't connect unless I reboot the router, only the computer running Ubuntu 16.04.1 has that problem, no other gadget or computer runs into that.

The computer has the Intel AC 3160 adapter, output of `sudo lshw -class network` is as follows:

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 3160
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlp7s0
   version: 83
   serial: d0:7e:35:fb:11:b1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-34-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=67.82.77.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:49 memory:f7100000-f7101fff
```

I am also running manual IPv4 settings to give it a static IP within the network, no duplicate IPs (ex. other device using the IP I assigned the computer) were found after troubleshooting the router first.

Comment: Does it work if you use DHCP instead of manual addressing? Cheers, Al

Comment: What manual address are you using, and, what addresses are assigned to the dhcp pool in your router? What address is assigned if you use dhcp? Cheers, Al

Comment: Added solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by modifying the configuration for the driver. I took this steps.

Open terminal, and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

There I added this line of code:

```
options iwlwifi fwlps=N swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1
```

Save changes & reboot.

The connection has been stable ever since, the speed of the wifi doesn't go above 54Mbps as the `11n_disable` option disables the 802.11N protocol. The `swcrypto` disables the software implementation of the cryptography interface and `fwlps` disables the power management option for the wireless adapter.

I tried using this options separately, or combinations of pairs but the only solutions that helped me solve my issue was using those three at the same time.